# Correct way of using isDigit() function in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I have studied some basics of C language. Here's my code snippet.

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a=108;
    if(!isdigit(a)) {
        cout<<"The number is not a digit";
    }
    else
        cout<<"It's a Number!";
    }
}
```

I dont know why, but it satisfies the condition. It should have outputted, `It's a Number!` Please correct me and also if u have a better solution to this, do suggest! (To make it more clear) I want to check whether the entered int is actually composed of digits. Thank you

Comment: `108` is ASCII for `l`. `std::isdigit` takes `int`, but not in the sense you're using.

Comment: What `int` is not composed of digits? If input is invalid, `bool b = std::cin >> a;` will give you `false`.

Comment: @LogicStuff, But user may enter anything! How do i Validate that ?

Comment: `if(std::cin >> a)` - this allows non-digit trailing characters though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see where your confusion comes from. The prototype of [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) says it takes a single `int` parameter; however, all parameters of type `int` are digits, so that would be pointless to check!

Here's when you can see the big difference between [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) and [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). The former shows little information, while the latter explains a lot more. cppreference gives you the real hint:

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF

The function is expecting a value between [0,127] and you can see on the page linked that the digits `0123456789` are represented by the numbers [48,57]. As others have pointed out, `108` is actually the ASCII character `l`.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 128; ++i)
{
    if (std::isdigit(i)) 
    {
        std::cout << i << " is a digit";
    }
}
```

You can't check a number like `108`, you would have to check each digit.

Comment: So then, How do i do it. Is there any simpler way out ?

Comment: @Milind: Changing `int` to `char` is pretty simple

Comment: @Tas: In what way is 108 not representable as an `unsigned char`? `unsigned char` goes up to 255 (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`).

Comment: @PreferenceBean any other way, you can think of ? coz, I have to do some calculations as well on that number.

Comment: @Milind: Are you sure you're not getting confused between a number, and a decimal, human-readable, string _representation_ of a number?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I'm not sure if you realise that there is a difference between a *digit* and a *number*. A digit is a single character from 0 to 9, a number is composed of digits.

Second, `std::isigit` has a lousy, confusing legacy interface. As [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) will tell you, it takes an `int` but requires its argument to be representable as `unsigned char` or EOF to avoid undefined behaviour. The `int` you pass to the function represents a single character; whether the mapping is according to ASCII or not is not mandated by C++ and thus implementation-defined.

Nevertheless, your C++ implementation very likely uses ASCII or a superset thereof. In [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), 108 is the lower-case letter 'l'. `isdigit` therefore returns false.

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit` uses the character representation of the `int` value `108`, which is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) for `l`, which is not a digit.

Comment: So then, How do I do it then ?? P.S Nice name you have got there !

Comment: @Milind: Do _what_? You haven't told us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

**Function Prototype of isdigit()**

```
int isdigit(int argument);
```

if you pass `a=108` to the function it will convert the value to it's equivalent [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) Value and return the result `false`. Because 108 is equivalent to `'l'` and `'l'` is not a digit.

Now pass `a = 48` to the function because 48 equivalent to `char '0'` now the function will `return` `true`.

You can also read [this](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/ctype.h/isdigit) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) tutorial for more.

Answer (score 0):

you are using isdigit wrong, as you were told in the answers above it's meant to be used with character representations, to check whether a certain char is a digit or not. you can check this page for more help on isdigit: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm

to your question - I guess you are trying to check if the number you are sending is a single digit number. for this you can simply do:

```
if (a >= 0 && a <= 9){
    // a is a single digit...
}
```